# Orderby Linq error when parse in a value

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, sql-order-by

I need a way to parse in a string as a variable for orderby in linq statement.
Here is my code:

```
var s = db.Vehicles.Where(c=>c.Model.body_style==b)
          .Select(u=> new{
                     u.Manufacturer.manufacturer_name, 
                     u.model_code, 
                     u.daily_hire_rate
            })
          .Distinct()
          .OrderBy(sort);
```

it gives me error:
The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.OrderBy(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, System.Func)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

I have heard about dynamic expressions api. but I don't know how to use it. I'm using mvc2 in vs2010. I'm not using model tho.

Comment: what does it mean `sort` in here?

Comment: its a string which comes from dropdown list. So the data should be sorted according to it. it has values from the database. ex. daily_hire_rate from vehicles table

Comment: You need to use dynamic linq. You just need to add the classes to your project and a using statement for the namespace.

Comment: where do I get those classes? do you know any links? I tried to find it but couldn't

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Dynamic LINQ, Scott Gu did a great post on it here http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

It makes it as easy as this

```
query = query.OrderBy(columnName);
```

or

```
//orderby descending
query = query.OrderBy(columnName + " DESC");
```